# AEM - Sightly : data-sly-attribute erasing css on tag

Tags: java, html, css, aem, sightly

I am currently working on components for AEM 6.0, I've noticed a quite strange behavior of the data-sly-attribute sightly attribute and I'm wondering if this is something that has been noticed by others (maybe a bug).

Take the following code:

**TEMPLATE** (*html*)

```
<div id="${properties.divId}" 
data-sly-use.attr="com.something.sightly.promoModel" 
     data-sly-attribute="${attr.attributeMap}">

     <a href="www.example.com" 
        class="btn btn-transparent" 
        data-sly-attribute.target="${properties.ckbNewWindow}" 
        **data-sly-attribute="${attr.attributeMap}"**>
       ${properties.ctaText}
    </a>

</div>
```

**Model** (*java*)

```
public class PromoModel{
    protected HashMap<String, String> attributeMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    @Override
    public void activate() throws Exception {
        attributeMap= ComponentUtils.buildDataAttributeMapFromResource(Constants.DATA_ATTRIBUTES_FIELD, getRequest());
}

public HashMap<String, String> getAttributeMap(){
    return attributeMap;

}
```

with buildDataAttributeMapFromResource function that basically populates the HashMap based on what content is in the component.

The issue is, when this code is executed on Author it works great but when I execute it on a Publisher the:

```
class="btn btn-transparent"
```

does not render.
It seems like data-sly-attribute is overwriting it and thus erasing it because if I change my template to this:

```
<div id="${properties.divId}" 
data-sly-use.attr="com.something.sightly.promoModel" 
     data-sly-attribute="${attr.attributeMap}">

     <a **data-sly-attribute="${attr.attributeMap}"**
        href="www.example.com" 
        class="btn btn-transparent" 
        data-sly-attribute.target="${properties.ckbNewWindow}">
       ${properties.ctaText}
    </a>

</div>
```

Notice that

```
data-sly-attribute="${attr.attributeMap}"
```

is in front of

```
class="btn btn-transparent"
```

it renders perfectly fine on Author and Publisher.

Bug ?
Maybe there is a fix for this out there that I'm not aware of ... ?
Any advice would be great.

Thanks
Nicola

Comment: Have you tried the XSS context? Here is the documentation: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/sightly/expression-language.html#Display Context

Something like **data-sly-attribute="${attr.attributeMap @context='styleString'}"**

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is likely the expected behavior. Here's a quote from [Adobe's docs](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/sightly/block-statements.html):

> Attributes are resolved left to right, with the rightmost instance of an attribute (either literal or defined via data-sly-attribute) taking precedence over any instances of the same attribute (defined either literally or via data-sly-attribute) defined to its left.

That would mean that if your attribute map contained a `class` attribute then it will take precedence over the literal class attribute if it's further to the right.